# Partial matching search of files in Django

Tags: python, django

Im doing the cs50 web course and working in Django.

I need to select md files based on the keyword that the user searches. If the query does not match the name of an the files, the user should instead be taken to a search results page that displays a list of all files that have the query as a substring. For example, if the search query were Py, then Python should appear in the search results assuming such file exists.

Problem is im not sure how. Also we arent using sql.

Here is util.py, code given by course that we are told we dont need to touch:

```
import re

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))


def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Here are my views function:

```
    def entry(request, title): #based on the url it shows a md file
        try:
            content = markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))
        except:
            return HttpResponseNotFound("Page not found")
    
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": content, "title": title.capitalize()
        })
    
    
    def search(request): 
        keyword = request.GET.get('q')
        result = util.get_entry(keyword)
    
        if result:  #if the keyword matches a title, return that result
            content = markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(result))
            return redirect('entry', result)

        else: #here i should return results that match the substring query
#stuck
            results = util.get_entry('%keyword%')
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/results.html", {
            "results": results
        })
```

Search bar:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

Comment: Which of the functions is `util.py` could you use if you need to search all of the titles? Try calling that in your view. If you're still stuck after that, then [edit] your question with your changes.

Comment: @alasdair list_entries() lists the titles of all the files that exist but it doesnt take an argument for it to be useful in this case.  While get_entry(title) returns a file only if its title and the search keyword fully match. I dont know how to look for files whose title partially matches with the keyword at all, and grab those using get_entry i guess?

Comment: @Alasdair like i could identify somehow all the titles that match and use those full titles to get_entry.  but dont know how to identify them, if im clear. because unlike sql where i could to smth like WHERE LIKE %WORD% i dont know how to search here. there is a folder named entries where files.md are saved & thats where im supposed to look

Comment: *but it doesnt take an argument for it to be useful in this case* - it doesn't search the list for you, but you could search the list yourself. You could loop through the list, and check whether it matches (try searching *python contains string* if you're stuck). If it matches, add it to a list of results. As an bonus, you could search for *list comprehensions* for a more Pythonic way to make the list.

Comment: @Alasdair damn should have thought of that myself lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using indexing in Python.
Here is how I did it.

```
list = ["Python", "CSS"]
q = "Py"

for i in list:
    for j in range(3):
        result = str(i[0:j])
        if result == q:
            print("One entry found: ", i)
```

**Output:**

One entry found: Python